# Converting world informations (PGW file - pixels) to geographical coordinates?

Tags: qgis, world-file

I'm trying to load an image on a [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com) map and to display it at the right place using the world information exported by QGIS.

For [image overlays](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#imageoverlay), Leaflet needs the coordinates of the upper left point and of the lower right point (boundaries):

```
var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]]; L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

In QGIS, when I export my image, I always use the 1:25000 scale and 72 DPI, which is a constant in my workflow.

[image]

It outputs a [world file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) (PGW) that contains the information:

```
8.86711729729699094 //xscale
0 //yskew
0 //xskew
-8.86711729729699094 //yscale
491355.98836270271567628 //xpos
6600748.93414135184139013 //ypos
```

Knowing all that information, is there a way to convert the world file information into geographical coordinates I could use in Leaflet?

Comment: Change your project CRS to EPSG:4326 before you export your image.

Comment: wow ! It works ! But it distorts my image which is now stretched on the X axis. Any chance to get the best of both ?

Comment: Not really, a geographic coordinate system isn't very good for displaying data other than near the equator.

Comment: Change your leaflet coordinate system maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out !  No need to check DPIs or map scale, all required informations are contained in the world file.
Here, I'm parsing a PGW file sent through a form.
I'm also using the [proj4php library](https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php) to handle projections.

```
public function get_overlay_bounds_from_pgw($pgwfile,$imagewidth,$imageheight){

    $filename = isset($pgwfile['name']) ? $pgwfile['name'] : null;
    if ( !$filename ) return new WP_Error('tdp_empty_pgw_file','Missing PGW file');

    $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ) );
    if ( !$arr_file_type || ($arr_file_type['ext'] != 'pgw') ) return new WP_Error('tdp_invalid_pgw_file','Invalid PGW file');

    $content = file_get_contents($pgwfile['tmp_name']);
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
    if ( count($lines) < 6 ) return new WP_Error('tdp_invalid_pgw_file','Invalid PGW file');

    //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file
    $world = array(
        'xscale'=>  $lines[0],
        'yskew'=>   $lines[1],
        'xskew'=>   $lines[2],
        'yscale'=>  $lines[3],
        'xpos'=>    $lines[4],
        'ypos'=>    $lines[5],
    );

    // Initialise Proj4
    $proj4 = new Proj4php();
    // Create two different projections.
    $projQgis    = new Proj('EPSG:3857', $proj4);
    $projLeaflet  = new Proj('EPSG:4326', $proj4);

    //
    $topleft = new Point($world['xpos'],$world['ypos'], $projQgis);
    $topleft = $proj4->transform($projLeaflet, $topleft);

    $xmeters = $imagewidth * $world['xscale'];
    $ymeters = $imageheight * $world['yscale'];

    $bottomright = new Point($world['xpos'] + $xmeters,$world['ypos'] + $ymeters, $projQgis);
    $bottomright = $proj4->transform($projLeaflet, $bottomright);

    $bounds = array(
        'north'=>   $topleft->x,
        'west'=>    $topleft->y,
        'south'=>   $bottomright->x,
        'east'=>    $bottomright->y,
    );

    return $bounds;
}
```